# No keyboard focus in unlock dialog XFCE

Tags: keyboard, xfce

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with the XFCE 4.12 desktop (Xfwm4 window manager) on an ASUS ROG laptop.
The primary screen is 2560x1440 joined to the laptop's own 1920x1080.

I have a small but nagging problem unlocking a session after it locks automatically while I'm having coffee.
As I return to the laptop the screen contains one single widget, the unlock dialog, unsurprisingly.
The problem is that, in most cases, it does not have keyboard focus, nor does it get focus by a single mouse click.

Restoring keyboard focus requires three (3) mouse clicks.
All three are necessary.

1. Click the username drop-down
2. Select the current user
3. Click the password field

At step 2 the dialog sometimes disappears and leaves a screen containing nothing but background.
I solve this by randomly pressing some of the function buttons in frustration, perhaps F8.
The dialog appears again.

My question: Is this a known problem? Does it have a standard solution?
Otherwise, in order to file a bug report I have a second question:
What component displays the unlock dialog, where should a bug report go?

Comment: The issue arises because both `xfce4-screensaver` and `light-locker` lock the screen. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133341/xubuntu-18-10-light-locker-wrong-behavior for how to disable light-locker, which solves the double dialog issue as well as an associated keyboard focus lock issue caused by this double locking. Still affects ubuntu `eoan` (19.10) and `focal` (20.04).

Answer (score 0):

Since I got no replies I filed a bug report to the XFCE project. However, what I see is seemingly the lightdm-gtk-greeter. So a kind admin propagated my bug report to the proper project. [It can now be found here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm-gtk-greeter/+bug/1824322).

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

Unfortunately, this issue is still unfixed, because on an (almost) fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 LTS with only xfce4 additionally installed, the lock screen still gets into the "can't focus password field" state.

(I know, this isn't really an answer, but adding a comment would require more reputation than I currently have)